# Day of Week plus x days

Tags: debian, date

As part of a Bash script how can I get the Day of the week + x days. This should be the Day of the Week (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, . . .)

e.g.

```
startDate='Sunday'
addDays=6
endDate=${startDate}+${addDays} #e.g. Saturday

or  

startDate='Tuesday'
endDate=${startDate}+${addDays} #e.g. Monday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GNU date!

```
startDate='Sunday'
addDays=6
endDate=$( date -d "${startDate} + ${addDays} days" '+%A' )

$ echo $endDate
Saturday
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date -d "6 days" +%A
```

Date uses the current date, so it can easily show the name what will 6 days later (       *%A     locale's full weekday name (e.g., Sunday)*)